# How to post mentions to slack incoming webhooks

Tags: javascript, webhooks, slack

The mentions I send to the incoming webhook renders as plain text.

Note: Sending post request using the request package.

Tried the following:

sending mentions as `<@userid>`

Result: `<@userid>` // as plain text

```js
request.post(
       `${channels[message.channel.name]}`,
       {
           json: {
               text: 
               'To: ' + mapDiscordToSlackNames(message.mentions.users) + '\n' +
               'Discord channel: #' + message.channel.name + '\n' +
               'Link:  <' + message.url + '|Link to post>' + '\n' +
```

Result: To: @soda // as plain text not as mention to @soda user

**Entire Code**

```js
// require the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const devs = require('./devs.json');
const channels = require('./channels.json');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
var request = require('request');

dotenv.load({
  path: path.join(__dirname, `.env`),
  silent: true
});

// create a new Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();

// Map discord usernames of devs to slack usernames
function mapDiscordToSlackNames(discordUsers) {
    return discordUsers.map( user => { 
        return '@' + devs[user.username];
     })  
}

// when the client is ready, run this code
// this event will only trigger one time after logging in
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Discord Connected!');
});

// on message on discord
client.on('message', message => {

    console.log(channels[message.channel.name]);
    request.post(
        `${channels[message.channel.name]}`,
        {
            json: {
                text: 
                'To: ' + mapDiscordToSlackNames(message.mentions.users) + '\n' +
                'Discord channel: #' + message.channel.name + '\n' +
                'Link:  <' + message.url + '|Link to post>' + '\n' + 
                'Original Message: \n' + 
                    '\t"' + message.author.username + ': ' + message.cleanContent + '"\n' + 
                    `Attachements:  ${message.attachments.map(attachment => attachment.url)}` 
             },       
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body);
            }
        }
    );
});

// login to Discord with app's token
client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

devs is a json object which has returns slack usernames corresponding to discord usernames.

Comment: please add the function `mapDiscordToSlackNames()` and how the resulting JSON looks like

Comment: And of course mentions work in general with incoming webhooks. The issue most likely is somewhere in the code.

Comment: function `mapDiscordToSlackNames()` returns a string of @username. In this eg. it returns '@soda' so the json becomes

`{ text: 'To: @soda' }`

Comment: usernames do not work though. only user IDs

Comment: Yeah. I tried returning userId as well in the form '<@userid>' but it just renders '<@userid>' in plain text

Comment: Looks to me that you are missing the brackets in your resulting text for the "to" line. Also it will only work with Slack user IDs, not usernames. something like `U12345678`

Comment: I tried with the angle brackets `'To: &lt;' + mapDiscordToSlackNames(message.mentions.users) + '&gt;'`and send the userid it results to `To: <@DBJRC9XDH>` again as plain text

Comment: I wasn't sure about which one is userid `CKYUDVCPQ/team/UBL0YA5F1` in the url so I used both before & after teams in this url. Goes as plain text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out I was sending userid by escaping '<' & '>' in string like

`'&lt@userid&gt'` and so it was passing as plain text.

> To mention someone in slack do 'To: <@' + userid + '>'
>
> The userid starts with U and can be found after the `team/` in url of
>   your workspace eg: `Cxxxxx/team/Uxxxxx/`

Comment: To be more precise, this should be in the message text to make it a mention `<@ULA15K66M>`, where ULA15K66M is the userid.

Comment: Note that I just tested and <@username> now works, too! Not just user id.

Comment: Yes, it works. However, it's better to use id. If anyone changes the username then depending on the use case, you might have issues. Id is independent of username and doesn't change despite changing username. Also, for channel mentions, id makes more sense, as there can be multiple channels with same name under different scopes.